# Java Csv-data String space split error

Tags: java, csv, arraylist, split, space

I am having some trouble with a command.

I have a file of the type csv which looks like this:

Merkmals-Nr.;Interne Teile-Nr.;Bereich;Fertigungsschritt;...

After reading the File in is want to read one Line and then split the line after ";" by using this codeline.

```
List<String> datenListe = Arrays.asList(data.split(";"));
```

Then I do a system.println

How the print should look:
    Merkmals-Nr.
    Interne Teile-Nr.
    Bereich
    Fertigungsschritt
    ...

How the print actually looks:
    Merkmals-Nr.
    Interne

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 2
    at java.util.Arrays$ArrayList.get(Arrays.java:2866)
    at CsvEinlesen.main(CsvEinlesen.java:23)
```

I figured out that the problem is caused by the space in "Interne Teile-Nr." but I don´t know how to solve the problem with the spaces.

This is thecomplete code:

```
import java.io.*;

import java.util.*;


public class CsvEinlesen {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    String fileName = "0-201-08-4473.csv";
    File file = new File(fileName);

    try {
      Scanner csvInputStream = new Scanner(file);

      while (csvInputStream.hasNext()) {
        String data = csvInputStream.next();

        List<String> datenListe = Arrays.asList(data.split(";"));

        for (int i = 0; i < 32; i++) {
          System.out.println(datenListe.get(i));
        }
      }

      csvInputStream.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
      System.out.println("CSV-Datei nicht gefunden");
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is it really necessary to convert the array to a `List<String>` if you still iterate through it like a normal array? Also why did you put `32` as a limit? This is not safe - exactly because you will end up getting errors like `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`.

My suggestion, for this example, is to just work with the array like this:

```
    //the rest of your code...
    while (csvInputStream.hasNext()) {
            String data = csvInputStream.next();

            String[] wordsInLine = data.split(";");

            for (int i = 0; i < wordsInLine.length; i++) {
              System.out.println(wordsInLine[i]);
            }
          }
   //the rest of your code ...
```

Give that a try and see if the error goes away.

Comment: Thanks your code solved one part of the problem. The other problem with the spaces I fixed with the command `code` scanner.useDelimiter(";");

Comment: Great stuff -well done. I am happy to help. Happy Coding!

Answer (score 0):

I was working today on a similar task (reading data from a CSV, but with "," separator). *If you're interested in keeping the order of the fields, and you know how many "columns" you'll have, you might wanna try a solution with a regexp.*

**Reasons to do so:**

- when splitting with method .split() for the line value1;;;value2;;
  you'll get an array like: arr[0]: value1, arr[1 ]: value2. This might
  not be really ok because you might wanna know what that value
  represents and you might have a hint if you know its order in the
  CSV, but you lose that information this way.
- using a regexp like the one I'll show in the example you'll be able
  to respect the order of the CSV values, and you might add the results
  to whatever you like, an array of Strings, ArrayList, List and so on
  (because you asked for ArrayList I'll make the example using that)
- you might learn to use group in regexp to get more specific info, and
  also could build more specific reg exps depending on your needs

**Cons:**

- maybe it's not an efficient way, in the meanings of time
- you could choose to split it by yourself using
  ".nextIndexOf(separatingChar)" to keep the track of the values
- maybe even other, I don't know

However, here's my solution:

```
public class RegExpSeparator {
    // if you have a convention for your CSV or file, that the first row
    // will contain the header you might count the header items and update the
    // column count so this method will be more generic
    // also to be more generic you can make a final var to store the separator
    // and append it to the stringbuilder in the method splitRow
    public static int columnCount = 7;

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        String testRow1 = "NaMe_wE132;-123.46;CEE Tue 23 Apr 1976 22:23:34;Value;Another_value;bla;blaa";
        String testRow2 = ";;Value1;;;;Value2";

        ArrayList<String> letsTestFirstCase = new ArrayList<String>(splitRow(testRow1));
        for (String item : letsTestFirstCase) {
            System.out.print(item + ";"); // we'll add and ; also at the end
        }
        System.out.println("");
        ArrayList<String> letsTestSecondCase = new ArrayList<String>(splitRow(testRow2));
        for (String item : letsTestSecondCase) {
            System.out.print(item + ";"); // we'll add and ; also at the end
        }
    }       

    private static ArrayList<String> splitRow (String toSplit) {
        StringBuilder buildPattern = new StringBuilder();
        //use this if you know how many columns you'll have, from the start
        for (int i = 0; i<columnCount-1; i++) {
            buildPattern.append("([^;]*);"); // to keep it simple I've assumed the fact that
            // you might have values like "Name_233, 23:45 PM, -123.45" and so on
            // * means 0 or more occurences of any char except for ;
        }
        buildPattern.append("([^;]*)"); //the last column will not be followed by a separator
        // the final regexp will be something like
        // (group1);(group2);...;(groupN)
        // and you might get the values by calling matcher.group(i)
        // where i will have values in the interval [1,N]
        // group(0) will return the WHOLE STRING!!
        String patternToString = buildPattern.toString();
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(patternToString);
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(toSplit);   // get a matcher object

        ArrayList<String> result = new ArrayList<String>();
        if (matcher.find()) {
            for (int i=1; i<=columnCount; i++){
                result.add(matcher.group(i)); // for the columns like ;; it will add the string ""
            }
        } else {
            System.out.println("Could not parse the given row");
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

You can learn more about regexp with examples from [TutorialsPoint.](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_regular_expressions.htm)

**NOTE:** You should make this as a separate class, like a util/handler one, just made it this way to have both main and the method here for the sake of the example. Good Luck!